# Javascript .scrollTop not working in iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, safari

I have a `React.js` component that contains functionality which loads more content from a MySQL database when the user scrolls down to the current last item (bottom of the screen). This works fine on all desktop browsers but seems to be being ignored when I view the site via Safari on iOS on my local network.

The `loadReleases()` function just doesn't fire. I assume it's something to do with the way iOS handles (or doesn't handle as the case may be) `.scrollTop`?

Any suggestions?

Here is the function :

```
window.onscroll = () => {
  const {
    loadReleases,
    state: { error, isLoading, hasMore }
  } = this;

  if (error || isLoading || !hasMore) return;

  if (
    window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
    document.documentElement.offsetHeight
  ) {
    loadReleases();
  }
};
```